# Use ElasticSearch client in non web application with Spring

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm creating a non web application with Spring that will read data from Kafka and write it in ElasticSearch, i included the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

When i execute the following code:

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("test-transactions");
    request.id("2");
    request.source("{\"name\":\"Sammie\"," + "\"lastname\":\"Goldner\"," + "\"username\":\"hugh.vonrueden\","
            + "\"amount\":9622235.2009}", XContentType.JSON);
    
    client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

If i include the following dependency the code works fine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But it brings a lot of other functionalities that i don't want in my code, is there any other way to configure **spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch** in a non web application?

Thanks.

Comment: Just disable mvc module.

Comment: But this is not the only dependency there, I understand i can disable most of them, i just want to check if there is a cleaner way, because I don't see why the elastic search api is dependent only in a web application

Comment: sure, use non spring api
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_maven_repository.html

Comment: I know i can use that, But I 'm trying to use spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch, and i want to heck if it is designed only for web applications, because there are a lot of types of  applications  streaming, standalone, etc?. All of them can use spring-boot but can't use a REST client, it doesn't make sense, there should be a clean way to use it

Comment: its not designed for web only, but uses those and not the other dependencies. Please don't make simple things hard.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to include the complete web starter dependency and exclude everything just for one class.

Comment: feel free to fork the libarary and use sdk URL for that for example.

Comment: You mean, you dont need web service API (like rest), in that case, you can use normal elasticsearch Java API, try using this link [Maven dependency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_maven_repository.html)

Comment: I will use it, but I was asking if there is a clean way to use it, because you can use all the spring data projects without any dependency with spring-web